# Gantt Chart in SharePoint-- Timeline view disappears

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, tasks, gantt-view

The first time I load the page, the timeline view of tasks appears no problem.  However, when I start to add an item, scroll along the timeline, or otherwise take an action on the page, the timeline view disappears for good.  I have to reload it to get the timeline to display again.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or can anyone comment on how I might go about fixing this?

There are only a few tasks, so it's not a volume issue. 
The only other modification I've made is to add a column called 'responsibility' to which I write in a subject value to identify the various stakeholders that might be involved.

Many thanks to anyone with more SharePoint experience that can offer some advice on this issue!

Comment: Is this on a site using a custom master page or styling?  Anything else on this site that is not out of the box SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? The Gantt view only really works with IE (unfortunately), although it seems to render just fine in Chrome and Firefox initially. It's not until you interact with it in those browsers that you'll notice it doesn't work.

[IE Tab for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US) is a great solution for getting IE functions (namely, Active-X controls) without having to actually use IE.